# How to Cancel Inprogress Download in .net core web api using file result?

Tags: c#

I have react which calls my api to download file. While downloading I want it to show the progress. Suppose the user wants to stop the download they have to cancel it. However, even if I cancel from UI it continues to download from the server side code. I have attached my source code and I want to know how to stop the download from the server.

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("[action]")]
        public FileResult DownloadPackageFile(string packageID)
        {
            log.Debug("DownloadPackageFile Starts");
            // Create HTTP Response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            try
            {
                log.Debug("DownloadPackageFile PackageId " + packageID);
                //File Extension
                string fileName = packageID + ".zip";
                // Set the File Path.
                string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), SolutionApiConstants.SolutionRepo, fileName);
                log.Debug("DownloadPackageFile : File Path " + filePath);
                // Check whether File exists.
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    //Throw 404 (Not Found) exception if File not found.
                    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    response.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("File not found: {0} .", packageID);
                    return null;
                    //throw new HttpResponseException(response);
                }
                byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip, fileName); // ZIP
```